# Appending a list to create a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to make a nested list in Python, by asking the user to input the text file.
The input file is as shown below:

`1.3 2.6 3.2 4.1
1 -3 2
-4.1`

And finally the output should be:
[[1.3, 2.6, 3.2, 4.1], [1.0, -3.0, 2.0], [-4.1]]

My code can display the individual list one below the other, but I'm having difficulty in appending the lists.
As I'm new to python, any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
My code is as follows:

```
#Ask the user to input a file name
file_name=input("Enter the Filename: ")

#Opening the file to read the content
infile=open(file_name,'r')

#Iterating for line in the file
for line in infile:
    line_str=line.split()

    for element in range(len(line_str)):
        line_str[element]=float(line_str[element])

    nlist=[[] for line in range(3)]
    nlist=nlist.append([line_str])
    print(nlist)
```

Comment: dont forget to close the file!

Comment: there are several lines in your file right?

Answer (score 1):

```
file_name=input("Enter the Filename: ")

# use "with" block to open file
# to ensure the file is closed once your code is done with it
with open(file_name,'r') as infile:
  # create "nlist" here and append each element to it during iteration
  nlist=[]
  for line in infile:
    line_str=line.split()
    # no need to iterate with range(len()); use a list comprehension
    # to map "float" to each list element
    line_str = [float(element) for element in line_str]  
    nlist.append(line_str)
  print(nlist)
```

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT] 
Sorry, I previously misunderstood your question and assumed that your input file is all in separate lines, but I think it is structured like

`1.3 2.6 3.2 4.1 
1 -3 2 
-4.1`

If you are simply asking how to append a list to a list to create a nested list in Python, here is how you do it:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8]
nested_list = []
nested_list.append(list1)
nested_list.append(list2)
```

This will result in:

`[ [1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7,8] ]`

I think the answer above gave a pretty concise answer with list comprehensions, but you can also do something with lambda functions as such:

```
# Ask the user to input a file name
file_name = input("Enter the Filename: ")

nlist = []

# Opening the file to read the content
with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ls = list(map(lambda x: float(x), line.split()))
        nlist.append(ls)

print(nlist)
```

In addition, you can even shorter this into a one-liner as such:

```
# Ask the user to input a file name
file_name = input("Enter the Filename: ")

# Opening the file to read the content
with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
    ls = list(map(lambda line: list(map(lambda x: float(x), line.split())), infile))
```

I hope this helped.